# SQLite Database where clause not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have a `sql database` consist of a column `Contact_Priority` which consist of integers as string entires (i.e. 1,2... but saved as string). `Contact_Priority` may contain a number more than once.  I am using following query to get the number of rows which contain a specific number.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, Contact_Priority + " =? ", new String[]{priority} , null, null, null);
        
        int count = cursor.getCount();
```

but it is returning 0, although there are some rows present in the database.

if i put `Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);`

I am getting correct number of rows. I am so confused why it is not working.

P.S. - `Contact_Priority` has `priority` in its row i.e. no typo error.
[image]

I just want to know how many number of rows has same priority.

**Update :-**

I don't know if it helps, but the app i am making assign some contact numbers to a given `Contact_Priority`. What i have done is, when i add a contact to any particular `Contact_Priority` i.e. 1,2 or so on, on a button click i can add then to all the priority i.e. priority 1 to 8 will have same contacts as you can see in the image above.

This i have implemented successfully, now while showing the contacts for a priority i am getting the problem but strangely it is working one particular priority, through which i set all the similar contacts.

Consider i choose to keep all the contacts of priority "2" then i am getting the correct output for "2" i.e. correct number of rows while for all others i am getting 0. I have checked that the database is updated and rows are update but why i am getting output for only one priority i cannot understand.

**Update 2**

The value of `priority` depends on the position of the `listview` which contains the button on whose `onClick` the query function is called. eg. Consider, I copied contacts of `priority` `2` to all others. The database is updated, like in image above. Now when i click on the button of `listview child 1` then priority is `1`, if i click on 2nd child's button then priority is `2` and so on. For some strange reasons, it is working priority is "2" (Since i copied contacts of "2" to all). for others it is not working.

Now if i had copied contacts of "priority 3" then it would have worked for only when priority is "3" (i.e. i clicked 3rd button on the list) and not working for anyone else.

I think i have made myself clear. Sorry for confusing you all, I myself am confused since i haven't seen any strange problem like this.

Comment: If you output the query that the sentence is generating you'd find the issue right away. Do so and paste it here.

Comment: i don't understand `Contact_Priority may contain a number more than once` ?

Comment: what is the value of the `Contact_Priority` variable ? of the `priority` variable ?

Comment: @njzk2 i mean it may have value 1 more than once and that is what i want to check.

Comment: more than once, do you mean a row may have several values at once, or do you mean that several rows may have the same value ?

Comment: (and please answer my other questions)

Comment: Shouldn't it simply be `"Contact_Priority =? "` (note the position of the quotes) ?

Comment: @njzk2 i don't think that makes a difference. Does it?

Comment: @MostyMostacho how to do that ?

Comment: @RohanKandwal : it makes a big difference if your `Contact_Priority` contains anything but `"Contact_Priority"`. Which it may or may not,no one but you can know.

Comment: The query is syntactically correct with correct column names etc. since there's no exception. It really boils down whether the `selection` matches a row or not. What is the value of `priority` selection arg?

Comment: @laalto i have updated the question please check.

Comment: @njzk2 i have updated the question please check

Comment: @Rohan, again what is the value of `priority` and where it comes from?   For example if it comes from an EditText it could contain whitespace that makes the selection not match.

Comment: what is the value of the Contact_Priority variable ? of the priority variable ? (bis)

Comment: @laalto priority is position of `listview` which contains the button. It consist of no whitespace, etc. I have checked using sqlite database browser. Also since it is working for one priority then it is correct. What i don't understand is why it is working for only one value?

Comment: @njzk2 priority is the position of `listview` converted to String.

Comment: what is the value of the Contact_Priority variable ? (ter)

Comment: also, what is the actual value of the `priority` in this specific case ?

Comment: @Rohan There's little additional information that helps to diagnose the problem for you. You could try examining the problem in debugger or add logging. Especially with the `priority` variable.

Comment: @laalto i tried. i checked priority value & no of entries in contacts both are showing correct values. I have no idea why only for one value it is working.

Comment: I dont'r understand how I could make myself more clear. You have a variable names `Contact_Priority`. You use it to create your selection in your query (`Contact_Priority + " =? "`). What is the value of this variable ?

Comment: @njzk2 I have a column named `Contact_Priority` which consist of values from 1-8 as you can see in the image above. `priority` may also contain values `1-8`.

Comment: @laalto please check my answer and post the reason if you can.

Comment: @RohanKandwal : In the code you posted, there is a java variable name `Contact_Priority`. We still don't know what it's value is.

Comment: @njzk2 `String Contact_Priority = "Contact_Priority";` and `Contact_Priority` is the name of the column in the database as you can see in the image above.

Comment: @RohanKandwal : Thank you. That eliminates a possible reason for the issue.

Comment: What happens if you query `Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);` and loop on the rows, and log the value for `cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(Contact_Priority)));`? Do you get the proper values ?

Comment: @njzk2 yep i get. see my answer below it is working when i am using `rawQuery` and i don't know why because both are one in same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this is working but using the following query i get desired result

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from Contact where Contact_Priority =" + priority,null);
```

Since both the queries are same i don't understand why this is working and the previous one not. I am mentioning this answer for all those who face similar problems. If anyone has clear answer what cause this query working and previous query not working please mention in comments.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you ever find the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html
What Contact_Priority variable's intent ? and why you use " =? " this string?

The definition of method which you are using is:

query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)

it should be something like this:
CONTACT_TABLE, null, Contact_Priority, new String[]{priority} , null, null, null, null

Comment: And if you put Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null, null); 

It should work, because you simply type "select * from Contact_Table"

Comment: This is not correct. `selection` is content from `WHERE` clause ([query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)), which accept parameters, specified in `selectionArgs`.

Comment: @ibrahimdemir : what's wrong with `= ?` in your opinion ? that's how the selection indicates the selectionArgs positions.

Comment: i have seen many examples using `=?` and they work perfectly. I also have used this in my current project in some other places and faced no problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, Contact_Priority + " =? ", new String[]{priority} , null, null, null);
```

will return all rows in which `Contact_Priority` (which I hope is a variable with `"Contact_Priority"`) are exactly equal to `priority` given.

You don't want exact, you want a match, so:

```
 .query(CONTACT_TABLE, null, "','||Contact_Priority||',' LIKE '%,'||?||',%'", new String[]{priority} , null, null, null);
```

will do!

EDIT: forgot wildcard character...

Comment: I have never seen this notation. can you explain what it does ?

Comment: @njzk2 It matches a item in a comma delimited list which may be first, last or within list. Try match `1` in `10,2,11`!

Comment: I don't understand how matching something in your list is relevant to the question ?

Comment: @njzk2 i don't know why but `like` is working but since i want specific query so it won't work in every condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well

```
String.format(Contact_Property + " = \'%s\'", priority);
```

and set the selectionArgs argument to null.

Comment: i don't see any reason why this should work any better. could you give one ?

Comment: like will return +ve count for similar values not exaclty

Comment: `like` uses the `%` sign as a wildcard. I you don't put any `%` in your argument, `like` behaves like `=`

Comment: I believe as long as we don't use any wild card character, it will work like an =.

Comment: exactly. so i don't see how it would change anything.

Comment: Putting the `?` in quotes turns it into literal and not a placeholder for selectionArgs.

Comment: No. Never **ever** use String.format without locale in an sql query. If your app runs in, say, arabic, you'll have surprises. I have written about this : http://njzk2.wordpress.com/2013/06/04/string-format-and-arabic-numbers/

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks for this invaluable info.

Comment: (the easy trick to overcome this issue is to specify the locale. Lint gives you a warning about that, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP, but have discovered what seems to be causing it.

My table using **FULLTEXT** search - e.g., `CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE my_table USING fts3 (...)`. And when I change it to a normal (non-virtual / non-fts3 / non-fts4) table, the problem goes away.

However, I need to keep it as a virtual/fts3 table, so the workaround I have used is the change my `selection` String from `_id = ?` to `docid = ?`. (The `docid` column is automatically created by Android/SQLite when you create a virtual/fts3 table.)

Of course, you can instead hardcode your id (e.g., 12345) using `_id = 12345` for the `selection` (with a null `selectionArgs`).